# How can i hook into a failed registration?

Tags: 8

I need to send an email to a user who tried to register, but the registration failed due to some reason.

How can I do this? where do I hook into? I thought about it and searched for a while,

- Hooking into hook_form_alter won't work because on submitting the form, I still don't know whether it would be a failed registration or not.
- Hooking into hook_user_insert also won't work because this would only fire when the registration is successful.

Comment: _on submitting the form, I still don't know whether it would be a failed registration or not_ Don't you? Beyond validation for the form failing, what do you class as "registration failed"?

Comment: registration failed could be because of username is already taken, could i make sure of this in form validation?

Comment: yes that gets checked in validation. I'm sure you can use `$form_state->getErrors()` to get existing ones in your own validation handler